# How to protect a full grain leather messenger bag?

Tags: clothing

The [recommendation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzXbuIfE0Vc) for leather products is to condition them with something like Venetian Leather Balm as soon as you buy it, then apply a water repellant spray.

My concern is that if I apply Venetian Leather Balm to a full grain leather messenger bag, the oil will stain and ruin my blazer and winter coats.

Is there a safe way to treat leather products without damaging clothes?

Comment: Generally, Yes/No questions are off topic here, and on any SE site. Instead you can ask e.g. "How to protect my messenger bag?" and get answers, among them might be "use this cream" where you can then ask in comments if it might stain your clothes.

Comment: BTW, why not use saddle soap?

Answer (score 2):

I did not use the balm you mention, so I cannot comment directly. However, as I wrote previously, I reconditioned leather products (including a leather jacket), the last action being - applying a layer of grease.

What I did about it had 2 parts:

1. I only applied as much grease as needed - no serious excess.
2. After I gave the grease a chance to penetrate the leather, I removed all the excess, to the best of my abilities.

I never noticed grease spots anywhere: clothes, furniture, accessories...

Answer (score 1):

I've always done what [this blog](https://leathermilk.com/tacky-leather-conditioned-leather) suggests:

1. Don't overcondition
2. Use a clean dry cloth to remove any excess
3. Allow conditioner to soak in and the surface to dry before using item

More is not always better!